# How to subtract a time constant in a LibreOffice/OpenOffice/Excel formula?

Tags: excel, time, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

In a LibreOffice/OpenOffice spreadsheet, cell A1 contains a time, as does cell B1.

Cell C1 contains the formula `=B1-A1`, which returns the difference between the times (which gives me the duration of an event).

Instead of C1 being the exact duration, I want it to be the duration minus 1 hour and 45 minutes.  I have tried `=B1-A1-1:45`, `=B1-A1-01:45`, and `=B1-A1-1.75` but none of these work.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `TIME()`

```
=B1-A1-TIME(1,45,0)
```

or put the time in quotes:

```
=B1-A1-"01:45"
```

Comment: Thank you Scott!  Quotes... so simple.  BTW, both your solutions work in OpenOffice and LibreOffice.  I'll accept your answer once stackoverflow lets me.