# How to subtract a time constant in LibreOffice calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to subtract 8 hours from a cell with a time in it (HH:MM)

I want to track whether I work more than 8 hours, or less than 8 hours each day.
If I work more, I should get a POSITIVE HH:MM result.
If I work less, I should get a NEGATIVE HH:MM result.

Here is what the spreadsheet should end up looking like:
[image]

A similar question was asked here, but I discovered the 'accepted' answer doesn't cover all cases.
[How to subtract a time constant in a LibreOffice/OpenOffice/Excel formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385485/how-to-subtract-a-time-constant-in-a-libreoffice-openoffice-excel-formula)

Comment: Because there's no such thing as a negative time?

Comment: What's the exact problem? Which cases aren't covered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385485/how-to-subtract-a-time-constant-in-a-libreoffice-openoffice-excel-formula ?

Comment: That is weird. I've got it working now it appears. I can't see what I changed to make it work. Just a simple formula like C5-"8:00" is giving me the negative minutes I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following custom format code works for me:

> `HH:MM;[RED]-HH:MM`

[image]

Comment: That custom format makes all my Short/over values RED.

Comment: I now have the RED vs Normal text working. Got it going in a separate spreadsheet, then copied the cells over the spreadsheet where it wasn't working.